# php - count elements in array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

I am trying to count elements in an array, but it doens't work as intended:

I have a while loop, which loops through my user table:

```
while($refsData=$refs->fetch()){
    $new_array = array($refsData['id']);
    print_r($new_array);

        $outcome = $rentedrefs->_paying($new_array);
    }
```

The `print_r($new_array);` gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 90427
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90428
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90429
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90430
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90431
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90432
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90433
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90434
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90435
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90436
)
```

Inside the `_paying` function, I count the number of values from the array:

```
function _paying($referrals_array){

echo count($referrals_array);


}
```

The problem is, that the above `count($referrals_array);` just gives me: `1`, when it should be `10`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On each iteration of your `while` loop you're overwriting `$new_array`.

Comment: Your array is only returning one element.  Look at your output.  Each array is Array[0].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new array at each step of the loop. Instead it should be written like this:

```
$new_array = array();
while($refsData=$refs->fetch()){
    $new_array[] = $refsData['id'];
    // print_r($new_array);
}

$outcome = $rentedrefs->_paying($new_array);
```

Note that I moved the `_paying` call outside the loop, as it seems to be the aggregating function. If not, you'd most probably make it process `$refsData['id']` instead - not the whole array.

As a sidenote, I'd strongly recommend using [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method (instead of fetch when you need to fill a collection with results of a query. It'll be trivial to count the number of the resulting array.

Comment: The while loop I showed in the question, is actually a nested loop. Meaning there is another while loop outside that loop. Will that be a problem, if I am placing the $outcome outside of that nested loop, but in the first loop?

Comment: You didn't show the outer loop, but the way I see it, the code I've shown is a direct replacement for what you have at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `$new_array` as a new array with the single element `$refsData['id']`. The count of 1 is therefore correct.

To get the number of results, either use a `COUNT(*)` select to ask your sql server, or add a counter to your loop, like this:

```
$entries = 0;
while($refsData=$refs->fetch()){
    $new_array = array($refsData['id']);
    print_r($new_array);
    $entries++;

    $outcome = $rentedrefs->_paying($new_array);
}

echo $entries;
```

Comment: This gives me "100" when I echo $entries

Comment: Then you have 100 results, I guess.

Comment: there is only 10 rows in the table.

Comment: Since i don't know your query, I can only guess. You could be generating a much larger number of results by joining the table with itself.

Answer (score 0):

It works properly, in each circulation of loop you have one array, so in first you have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 90427
)
```

in 2nd:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 90428
)
```

and so on.

It should work properly:

```
var $count = 0;
while($refsData=$refs->fetch()){
    $new_array = array($refsData['id']);
        $count += count($new_array);    
        $outcome = $rentedrefs->_paying($new_array);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding elements to an array, but creating a new array each iteration. To add elements, just do:

```
$new_array[] = $refsData['id'];
```